# ARCore – Disable a movement of ModelRenderable

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

Here is the piece of code using which I am able to place the model.

```
private void addNodeToScene(ArFragment fragment, Anchor createAnchor, ModelRenderable renderable) {

    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(createAnchor);
    TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(fragment.getTransformationSystem());
    transformableNode.setName("box");
    transformableNode.setRenderable(renderable);
    transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode);
    fragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);

    transformableNode.setOnTapListener((hitTestResult, motionEvent) -> {
        if(callback != null) {
            callback.onGiftClick(hitTestResult.getNode());
        }
    });
    transformableNode.select();
}
```

But once the model is placed, I can move the model around.

Is there any way I can disable the user from moving the model around once it has been placed?

Comment: use simple Node() if you don't want your model to me moved. TransformableNode is used for transformation purpose only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your TransformableNode with a Node.

```
TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(fragment.getTransformationSystem());
```

becomes

```
Node myNode = new Node();
```

you won't be able to move it then anymore

Some things work differently with Nodes as opposed to TransformableNodes -> The constructor being empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep TransforableNode, you can go with following flag

```
transformableNode.getTranslationController().setEnabled(false);
```